# How can I add IP Addresses/w Withlists as login IP ranges at the profile level?

Tags: login

I would like to restrict access to users at a profile level.
Now when I asked my client for the login IP ranges, they gave me for example this IPs (this is only a muster or example):

60.149.164.0/26 – Needs to be whitelist
120.244.128.48/29 – Needs to be whitelist

I can not get it, how can I use this information in order to add them as Start IP Address and End IP Address for the Login IP Addresses at the profile level.

Can please somebody help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address you have been given are in CIDR format. You can use [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks) to find the specific offset (the column "Difference to last address") corresponding to the block size (the /number). Add that offset to your start address to get the end address.

Comment: Thanks David. What you mean and according to your link is: for 60.149.164.0/26 the End IP Address would be:   60.149.164.63?                  (DIfference +0.0.0.63). For the second one, 120.244.128.48/29 the End IP Address would be  120.244.128.55 (Difference to last address +0.0.0.7)?

Comment: That is correct.